# TLS for java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security

I want to integrate TLS in to my java spring project and when i research for it i found out that the tls is implemented like ssl in java spring document(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#server-properties -->server.ssl.protocol) but if you search it the differences on google they are different so what should i do? The implementation is same?

Comment: TLS [superseded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) SSL as the implementation, but they both achieve the same thing, so you should read `SSL` as `TLS/SSL`. The property names are a blast from the past.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks..@Kayaman